# Get latest 2 values from status in rxjs store

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, store, angular2-observables

I need to keep track for the changes on the latest id on the store, so I need to get the value before the change and after the change.

```
 this.store.select(currentSearchSelector).subscribe(search => {
      this.currentSearchId = search.id;
      console.log('current ' + this.currentSearchId);
      // I need to detect the change on this id in the store
    });
```

What is the right thing to keep an eye on the latest change without loosing the previous change?

E.g: if the currentSearchID = 21 then change to 22 I need to detect this change.
On the subscription I had, the listner will keep getting the latest change only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your question!

I think you could use the [bufferCount](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/buffercount.html) operator with the value of 2.

It will create an observable that will **emit values only when the buffer is full** and emits the **values as an array**. To find more info you can check the [official documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/buffercount.html).

P.S. The size of the buffer should be 2 in your case.

```
this.store.select(currentSearchSelector)
    .pipe(bufferCount(2))
    .subscribe(([previousSearch, currentSearch]) => {
       this.currentSearchId = currentSearch.id;
       console.log('current ' + this.currentSearchId);
       console.log('previous ' + previousSearch.id);
    });
```

Also, there is an example with the `bufferCount` operator [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-vvccar?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100)

## Update

The [pairwise operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/pairwise.html) is a more specific version of bufferCount that just emits the last two items together and is probably more appropriate here.

Whichever you choose you probably also need to couple it with a [filter operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html) to check for the change in the search ID.

Comment: I am trying the bufferCount but still having the same current id for both previous and current search

Comment: @palAlaa Angular-ish [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-plhela).